# What controls when text in a <TD> line wraps?

Tags: html, css, html-table, formatting

I have the following text in a `<TD>`
`Form submitted at 11:11am on Friday 24th of June, 2011`

It is appearing in FF5 as
`Form submitted

at 11:11am on

Friday 24th of

June, 2011`

I look at the CSS styles in FireBug and can't see any reason for this.

I would liek to see it all on one line, but I don't want to set a width and I don't want to stuff the text with `&NBSP;`

I am curious as to how this happens, and also what the least effort solution is that would give me the complete text in a `<TD>` (when the browser window is wide enough)

Comment: the width of your `<td>` would probably determine this, but without seeing any html, css styles or working examples it's pretty hard to determine exactly what your issue is.

Comment: @AlastairPitts: I think he means when there are several cells in a row with text/content, but none of them have a set width.

Comment: @Wesley Murch: fair enough, it's just annoying to guess when it would be so easy just to show us.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To force it to be one line you can use the [white-space:nowrap](http://www.w3schools.com/css/pr_text_white-space.asp)